# Better way to write generic method to convert List<List<T>> to T[][]

Tags: java, array, generics

I was working through getting myself past the creation of a generic method, that converts a `List<T>` or `List<List<T>>`, to `T[]` or `T[][]` respectively. Well, let's just consider a maximum dimension of 2 for now.

### `List<T>` to `T[]` is quite straight-forward:

```
public static <T> T[] listToArray(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {

    /**** Null Checks removed for brevity ****/

    T[] arr = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Now I can call this method as:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("rohit", "jain"));
String[] arr = listToArray(list, String.class);
```

---

### `List<List<T>>` to `T[][]` is what gives problems:

Now, here's the problem. Consider the code:

```
public static <T> T[][] multiListToArray(List<List<T>> listOfList, Class<T> clazz) {

    // Here I don't know what size to give for 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension
 // T[][] arr = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, listOfList.size(), ?);

    // So, I tried this. But this of course is not type safe
 // T[][] arr = (T[][]) new Object[listOfList.size()][];

    /* Only alternative I had was to iterate over the listOfList to get the
       maximum out of all the column sizes, which I can give as 2<sup>nd</sup>
       dimension later on. 
    */
    int maxCol = 0;

    for (List<T> row: listOfList) {
        if (row.size() > maxCol) {
            maxCol = row.size();
        }
    }

    // Now I can pass `maxCol` as 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension
    T[][] arr = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, listOfList.size(), maxCol);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size(); ++i) {
        List<T> row = listOfList.get(i);
        arr[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[])Array.newInstance(clazz, row.size()));
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Now, this is what I want to avoid - double iteration of `List<List<T>>` to be able to create the array. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are creating new instance of arrays in your second loop, you don't need to know the size of the "inner list". Your "outer array" has to be as big as the "outer list". In a second phase, you instanciate the "inner arrays".

There's a simple way do this:

```
public <T> T[][] multiListToArray(final List<List<T>> listOfList, final Class<T> classz) {
    final T[][] array = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.size(), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.get(i).size()));
    }

    return array;
}
```

More over, as you can see in the code above, you can provide a 0-length array to `toArray(T[])` method.

This piece of code:

```
final List<List<String>> test = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
test.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")));
test.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f", "g")));
test.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("h", "i")));

for (final String[] innerArray : multiListToArray(test, String.class)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(innerArray));
}
```

Will produce this output:

> [a, b, c]
>   [d, e, f, g]
>   [h, i]

**EDIT:** There is [an Ideone example](http://ideone.com/9dxEId).

**EDIT 2:** Code and Ideone updated to comply with OP needs.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the 1st part. Yeah, I missed that point, that I can give 0 size for column initially. And regarding giving `0` size for array inside `for` loop, I would prefer to pass the size of the list, so that array don't need to be re-created in the method. Anyways thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: So you could replace `array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classz, 0));` with `array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.get(i).size()));` ;)

Answer (score 3):

you could always reuse your existing listToArrayMethod to solve your problem

```
public static <T> T[][] multiListToArray(List<List<T>> listOfList, Class<T> clazz) {

    //unsure if this line will work but it should
    Class<List<T>> listClass = (Class<List<T>>) listOfList.get(0).getClass();

    List<T>[] arrayOfLists = listToArray(listOfList, listClass);
    T[][] array = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(clazz, arrayOfLists.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLists.length; i++) {
        List<T> arrayOfList = arrayOfLists[i];
        array[i] = listToArray(arrayOfList, clazz);
    }
    return array;
}
```

basically this works because we just have a list of list so we convert that to an array of list then we convert each of those to an array and place those inside our new array.

Answer (score 0):

"Is there any possibility?"

Seems to be the *only* possibility...

```
/// A generic method to convert a list of lists to a two dimensional array
//
<T> T[][] makeArray ( List<List<T>> list ) {        int i = 0;
    T[][] makeArray = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(list.get(0).get(0).getClass(),list.size(),0);
    for( List<T> tt : list )
        makeArray[i++] = (T[]) tt.toArray();
    return makeArray;
}
```